# Convert a conditional join in SQL to pandas

Tags: pandas

How can I do this is pandas?
Basically I have df1, to which I will join df2, but based on what a df2 record contains, the join key changes

```
select coalesce( t2.age,t3.age) as age 
from df1 t1 left join df2 t2 on df1.id=df2.id and df1.Id is not null and df2.id is not null
left join df2 t3 on df1.name = df2.name and df1.name is not null and df2.name is not null and t3.title='Manager'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are Convert `SQL` to `pandas` ,just using `pandasql`

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

q1 = """select coalesce( t2.age,t3.age) as age 
from df1 t1 left join df2 t2 on df1.id=df2.id and df1.Id is not null and df2.id is not null
left join df2 t3 on df1.name = df2.name and df1.name is not null and df2.name is not null and t3.title='Manager' """

print(ps.sqldf(q1.replace('\n',''), locals()))
```